# Migration Azure DevOps Services on the my DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-server

My company needs to migrate Azure DevOps from cloud to server without data loss. In descriptions and instructions, there is only the possibility of transferring to services. Tell me how can I transfer the data to my servers and deploy the service there?
Used OpsHub Azure DevOps Migrator, but migration from server not supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way from Azure DevOps to self-hosted servers without loss. The [official migration tools only work from server to cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops).

Azure DevOps is generally months in advance of Azure DevOps Server and has features on it that don't even exist on Azure DevOps Server. Because of this, the datamodel is perpetually backwards incompatible.

There has been 1 short time period in 2015 when it was possible to move off of the service. I migrations and upgrades I still encounter a few of those and they all have issues with strange edge cases, cause upgrade failures etc.

---

There are tools that can transfer work items, changesets, git repos, pipelines separately, but they don't transfer without loss and can't transfer everything.

These tools will replay the work item changes, TFVC changesets, package feeds and pipeline artifacts. This may cause data loss, generates new IDs and changes the Creation, Changed and Closed dates etc.

[OpsHub Azure DevOps Migrator](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-azure-devops-migrator/) can migrate between Servers and from Azure DevOps to Azure DevOps Server, but not without data loss.

[NkdAgility's Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/) can migrate and sync work items between severs as well as cloud. There's a [great hands-on lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/devops-lab/moving-work-items-around-using-the-azure-devops-migration-tools?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&).

Comment: And how then, for a start, to save yourself a project in general, so as not to lose data in critical situations?

Comment: One way it to ensure you set tight permissions to prevent accidental mistakes. It's also good to remember that most destructive operations can be undone by support.

Comment: Git repos and wikis can easily be mirrorer or locally cloned. Same goes for artifact feeds.

Comment: Work items require special commands to destroy and by default won't lose any of their data.